# Rendering results from an API after using a search function with Backbone.js

Tags: api, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone.js and I am trying to create an application that can check if you completed the videos games you control.

I am using an API to retrieve any information about videogames.

I want to be able to search for a game, for example "Zelda". It should then list every Zelda game.

I get stuck because I don't know how to get the search function to work properly with the API and I don't know how to render it properly. I have written a template for the games that should render.

I have no clue what to do know, or if I'm even on the right track. I am not asking for someone to code it completely, I am asking for a step in the right direction.

Let me know if you need more code.

#### library_view.js

```
var LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el:$("#games"),
  url: url = "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/search/?api_key=[KEY]",
  events:{
    "keypress input":"findGames"
  },

  findGames:function(e){
  if(e.which == 13){
    query = $(".searchfield").val()
    field_list = "name,platforms"
    resources = "game"
    url = url +"&query="+ query +"field_list"+ field_list +"resources"+ resources
  }
},
```

#### index.html

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Find a game" class="searchfield">
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mashing together a View and a Model.
A view, for instance, shouldn't have URL inside it, it doesn't know what to do with it.

The correct path would be something roughly like so:

```
var SearchModel = Backbone.Model.extend();

var LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $("#games"),

  events:{
    "keypress input":"findGames"
  },

  findGames: function(e){
    // get query, field_list, resources
    var searchModel = new SearchModel()
    searchModel.fetch({
      url: "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/search/?api_key=[KEY]"+"&query="+ query +"field_list"+ field_list +"resources"+ resources
    });
    // do something with searchModel 
  }
});
```

After the fetch, searchModel will hold the data Backbone Model style.
Let's say the returned value from the AJAX call is:

```
{
  "answer": 42
}
```

Then:

```
searchModel.get("answer") // = 42
```

The SearchModel is just an abstraction here as you don't really need it (you can just ajax it). But I put it to help you understand what Model represents, it basically represents only data... It doesn't know what View is.